# How to fix this ".NetFramework" warning in windows application C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.8

I have using Visual Studio 2012 with .NetFW 4.8

when I try to start my project I get this warning

> Warning   2   The primary reference "Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", which is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

for solve my problem I searched many time in google but I could not found any solution

I try retarget another .NetFW but this can't fix 
for publish and install my project in another computer this warning must to be solve
sorry for my bad english

Comment: The warning contains the instructions you need to follow.

Comment: Visual Basic 8 shipped in 2005 (on .NET Framework 2.0]. The current version is VB 16. You're going to want to update your VB version. If you need VB 8, target Framework 3.51 (aka 3.5sp1)